# PhoneGap - rapid deployment and test on device

Tags: cordova

I'm currently developing an app using PhoneGap and I've bumped into the following situation:

- I  want to have fast steps where I'm writing code and then to execute it on device.

The current solution to use hydration takes about 2-3 minutes to deploy a small (but important) change. That takes too long :( for me.

Is there another method that can be used?

Comment: So plug in your device and run on it. Or I understood you wrong ?

Comment: How about testing from Windows, an app on a iOS device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Deploy your PhoneGap App to your device with whatever plugins/native code you need.
2. Setup a webserver on your development machine with the js/html as you want it to run inside your PhoneGap app.
3. Be sure that the development machine and the phone are in the same network.
4. Use Safari on the Mac to get a remote debugging session and point your WebView to the webserver:
   `window.location = 'http://192.168.0.100/app/index.html';`
   The URL should point to the IP of your development machine and the location of your app, of course.
   (Be sure to have a wildcard `*` in your external hosts config)
5. Once you want to test your changes simply fire up the remote debugger again and do:
   `window.reload(true);`

If you want me to describe some steps in more detail just ask.

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Build your app so that it doesn't need phonegap plugins for most of the functionality. Where you need to use native code, include a fallback that works on a desktop browser.

That way you can do most of your debugging in chrome, with fast refresh and a full set of developer tools for the html and css adjustments. It takes a bit more thought setting up your app design, but being able to run the app in 3 seconds instead of 10 minutes is a huge difference in productivity.

The pattern I use is for this is setting up alternative functions for each platform:

```
app.someFunction = {}

app.someFunction.cordova = function() {
    // plugin call here
    }
app.someFunction.web = function() {
    // return some test data
    }

app.someFunction[app.platform]();
```